# How would I go about re-projecting the Blue Marble raster maps into a robinson projection using free tools?

Tags: coordinate-system

I would like to convert the NASA Blue Marble maps into a robinson projection.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that you have a spatially referenced blue marble image then you can use [gdalwarp](https://gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) to do it.

I found [these instructions](https://gothos.info/2009/04/transform-projections-with-gdal-ogr/) on how to acquire the correct paramters for the Robinson projection

> First, go back to spatialreference.org and search for Robinson. Its ID code is ESRI 54030 – not part of the EPSG library. Click on the link for the projection to open its window. You’ll be able to look at the projection data in a number of standard file formats. Select OGC_WKT from the list, and it will open the text in a new window, showing you the parameters of that projection. In your browser, go up to file, save as, and save the file as robinson_ogcwkt.txt in the same directory as the shapefile you want to reproject.

so something like

```
gdalwarp -t_srs robisnon_ogcwkt.txt bluemarble.tif robinsonBM.tif
```

should do it.

If you need to generate a spatially referenced Blue Marble image see my [notes](https://web.archive.org/web/20121130223652/http://ian01.geog.psu.edu:80/geoserver_docs/data/bluemarble/bluemarble.html).